# Setting TD value by class

Tags: jquery-ui, class, html-table

I have below code in a form for which i don't have access to and can not write any code. But in my webpage i have created another form where i can write some script.

My requirement: I have a dropdown and on selection of value from this i need to change the value of another drop-down field which is in different drop-down.
I tried the below script but not working.

Appreciate any help regarding this. Coding is not my profession but i am willing to learn.

```
enter code here

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function doStuff() {
alert($('#donation_campaign').val());
$('#PC1184$ddlDesignations').html($('#donation_campaign').val());
}
// ]]></script>
<h1>Thank you for support</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><label>Select your supporting chapter</label> <select id="donation_campaign"     name="donation[campaign]" onchange=" doStuff()"><option value="Corpus Fund">DC Metro</option><option value="8">Boston</option><option value="13">AZ</option><option value="24">Austin</option><option value="13">JDU</option><option selected="selected" value="13">Common Pool</option></select></p>
```

---

form code for which i dont have access to:**

```
<tr id="PC1184_trDesignation">
            <td class="BBFieldCaption DonationFieldCaption     DonationFieldDropDownCaption">
            <label for="PC1184_ddlDesignations" id="PC1184_lblDesignationCaption">Designation:</label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="BBFieldControlCell DonationFieldControlCell">
            <select name="PC1184$ddlDesignations"    id="PC1184_ddlDesignations" class="BBFormSelectList DonationSelectList">
            <option selected="selected" value="8">General Unrestricted Fund</option>
            <option value="13">Corpus Fund</option>
            <option value="24">Education Fund</option>

        </select>               
        </td>
    </tr>
```

---

Thanks in advance,
Naveen

Answer (score 0):

The script tag is processed by browser at the moment it appears in the HTML, the code is executed at that very moment. To postpone the execution, you should bind the code you've written to later event, like page load:

```
$(document).ready(doStuff);
```

Also, your function seemingly needs to be called everytime when first element is changed. So you need to bind it to change event of this element as well.

```
$('#donation_campaign').change(doStuff);
```

put these two lines at the end of your script.

At first, simplest solution is to have `updateEverything` javascript function that calculates all dependencies and modifies all necessary elements on the page, ensuring everything is correct. And you call this function at the page load and at changing of any element that is involved in dependencies tracked.